# Again on @ViewScoped misteries

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, scopes

I have already asked about @ViewScoped managed beans here:

[Commandlink action and @viewscoped weird behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007749/commandlink-action-and-viewscoped-weird-behaviour)

Unfortunately in the books and documentation about JSF I have there are only hints to the @ViewScoped annotation and its behind the scenes mechanisms are not unveiled.
So, after some terrible headaches with my JSF beans, I did some test on Mojarra 2.1 and I got some new weird (to me) results.

First of all doing successive Get requests to the same page the linked @ViewScoped managed bean is re-created every time. I would have expected the same behavior of successive Post to the same page, that is the managed bean survives between the posts and it is not created again.

When a new @Viewscoped managed bean is created that doesn't  imply the previous one is destroyed. Surprisingly (for me) it remains accessible for some time. I noticed this fact using the browser back button (I know it is a no  no ): I could retrieve some detail data from a managed bean which was supposed to be 'expired' because a new one, with different filter data, was created.

Can you confirm my results are correct ? Where can I find infos on the @ViewScoped internal mechanisms without having to look at its code ?

Thanks 
Filippo

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to take a look at BalusC's excellent article ["Communication in JSF 2.0"](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) with a chapter on the topic why `ViewScoped` beans sometimes behave like `RequestScoped` ones ([@ViewScoped fails in tag handlers](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers)).